# Com Docker, devo usar o Composer no container ou no host?

Tags: php, composer, docker

Tenho algumas dúvidas quanto ao ambiente de desenvolvimento. Tenho um projeto em Laravel e estou utilizando o Docker. Quando for utilizar o Composer ou o Artisan do Laravel, qual é o local indicado para se fazer isso? Na minha máquina host ou no container do Docker?

Comment: A ideia do container não é a facilidade ? Porque iria deixar o PHP fora ?

Comment: Se for utilizar o docker o ideal seria criar um container docker com suas configurações do laravel , depois disso nesse mesmo container você pode utilizar o composer para instalar components terceiros ou criar os seus proprios. Hoje vi um exemplo muito interessante. laradock.io/getting-started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se há necessidade de reaproveitar os pacotes em cache para outros projetos (*quando instala um pacote o composer guarda em cache **para não baixar novamente caso crie ou instale o pacote noutro projeto***) então recomendo que use o composer do host, mas se isso não fizer muita diferença pode usar o composer do container.

Tenha em conta que, para o efeito deve estar usando uma [imagem](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images) que trás o composer instalado ou poderá ainda criar sua própria imagem contendo toda stack que quiser.

Caso queira usar imagens prontas (com php, composer.. etc) recomendo o [ambientum](https://github.com/codecasts/ambientum).